# How to keep my android app hearing for updates?

Tags: php, android, updates

Hello there and happy new year 2013!!

I returned to my app after vacation, and now I want it to keep alive and hearing for updates!! Does anyone knows how to do so? I don't mean a complete answer, I mean like guidence, orientation!! Because I don't know how to start doing it!! And on the other hand, how do I send the updates from my PHP/PostgreSQL server? Has anyone did something like this before that could help me?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @VladPreda, of course you can push notifications from php. Why shouldn't you be able to?

Comment: You can try to push the notifications, but if (for example) the phone has no internet, you can try as much as you want and it won't work. That's why you need a php service, and android to check it periodically.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to PUSH updates to your application, you can do so using GCM: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

If you can simply have your application POLL for updates periodically, then you can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) to have your application hit your PHP endpoint as needed.

The choice of which to use usually comes down to how timely the updates need to be and how often they are likely to occur (taking into account battery, network, and other resource usage and so on).

To get started with GCM using PHP check out: [Android Push Notifications using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), PHP and MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

And, here's a good example of [AlarmManager/IntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) (and handling wake locks).

Comment: Here's a guide for [GCM + PHP](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Comment: Hello!! Thanks for your reply!! If I understood you correctly, GCM is used to send data updates (which is my issue) to the device, and AndroidManager/IntentService is used to look up for data updates in the server from the device, isn't it? But I only have to implement one of them right? In this case, I'm not selling the app quite yet, so I don't know in which devices will run. I'm just using a Galaxy Tab to test the app functionalities!! Which of the techniques would you use considering this issue?

Comment: GCM should only be used to notify the app that there is new data on the server, not to send the actual data. After receiving the GCM push notification, your app needs to download the new data from the server.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use GCM to send push messages to the device the app is running on, simply because the GCM service is always running and it will use less battery than polling.

As a side note: don´t send the actual data via push notifications, instead just send a notification that there is new data on the server. The app can then download the new data from the server.

Comment: GCM will not necessarily use less battery than polling, it depends on how often you use either. (And a not--too-often) poll with AlarmManager/IntentService and inexactRepeating can be done in a fairly battery friendly way.)

Answer (score 0):

If by update you mean and update in version that is a user has version 1 of your app but there is version 2 available then you could do it like this :

You could have a variable that would save the current app version, then every time the user starts the app you should connect to your server to check the most up to date version. You then can compare and show an alert if the user has a lower version than the one you currently have in your server.

Two important things here : Every time you update your app you should look for the value of the version variable and change it and you should have the current app version variable in your server updated as well

If you mean updates in the data then your best bet is to use the GCM service (Google Cloud Messaging)

Comment: There's no reason to store a variable or keep track of it. You can check the app-version from PackageManager quite easily.

Comment: Hello!! Thanks for your reply!! No, I'm not talking about version updates, just updates of the data!! Picture this, The client downloads, for the first time, data from the server (in my case, forms), but in the course of the day those forms may change or there are new forms to download!! To avoid the client look up for those updates, I want to send the updates directly to the device, or at least tell the client "Hey, there new info in the server!". That's what I want to do!!

Comment: Oh! That´s! What! You! Want! To! Do!!

Comment: You should use GCM. You need a script on the server side that would add payloads to your database then have a cronjob to check for this payloads and send them to the GCM servers. The payload won't have the new data but should have just a small message to notify the user about the new forms. Once the user gets the alert and starts the app, your app is responsible for taking any further actions.